# import java files from another folders

Tags: java, import

I have two folders:

```
Network/
 + Network.java
Router/
 + Router.java
```

Is there any way in java to import Network.java into **Router/** folder? Or I can only copy it directly into a folder for this to work?

Answer (score 1):

You can import things from nearby folders using [packages](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/packages.html).

For instance, if you have this file structure (in which I have changed the names of the folders to lower case):

```
network/Network.java
router/Router.java
```

And you have

```
package network;
```

at the top of `Network.java`, and

```
package router;
```

at the top of `Router.java`, then you can import `Network` into `Router.java` using:

```
import network.Network;
```

This assumes that you are trying to import a public class, declared inside `Network.java` as:

```
public class Network {
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

IDE:
If you're using an IDE like Netbeans oder Eclipse, you can just drag and drop the file to the package required. After this action the IDE will perform some refactoring and that's it. For more details refer to the posting above.